# How to read configuration file from a ASPX?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

How could you do to read a web.config file from  inside a aspx file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want to read the AppSetting parts of the web.config. Each diffrent area of the web.config file gets loaded a different way.  But the appSetting are intended for user variables.

`WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VariableName"];`

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="VariableName" value="xxxx"/>
    </appSettings>
....
```

Comment: +1 WebConfigurationManager (from System.Web.Configuration) is the correct object to use in ASP.NET, not ConfigurationManager

Comment: Thanks,  I got it to work like that, just had to add the full name :P

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to check application settings? Connection strings?

Go through `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

```
.AppSettings[int index or string name]
.ConnectionStrings[int index or string name]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourPropertyHere"];
```

as in

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your after the AppSetting section (name/value pairs) then this article will show you a good example of how to read them:

http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx